# Fluxbox: is there a problem with java modal dialogs and fluxbox?

Tags: java, fluxbox

I have got a java application that opens a modal dialog. The modal dialog is shown behind the main window and there is no way I can bring the modal dialog to front. If I switch to Cinnamon everything works as expected but not in Fluxbox. See the screenshot:

[image]

The window with the title "JNLP file" should be shown in front. Even when I try to bring it with the mouse it stays in behind. Is there any way to fix it?

PS. When I press `ALT-TAB` the java applicaton is not amoung the ones selectable (using `bbkeys`).

Comment: Do you have the issue with this (java) application only? If not, maybe something about the [focus model](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox.php) in the _fluxbox menu_?

Comment: can you rightclick the dialog @ the titlebar to bring up the window-menu and raise it's layer?

Comment: @illuminÉ It happens only with java applications. I suspect that too, something wrong with the focus model.

Comment: @akira it works when I raise, but when I close and open it, I have to raise the layer again.